# 3 way video calling on skype

Tags: skype, conferencing

Is it possible to use video on a group call in skype?

I have the video working great for regular calling but it seems like the video just disapears when I try to start a group call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use video on a group
>   call in skype?

no, Skype does not support video conferencing.

have a look a **[ooVoo](http://www.oovoo.com/)** (but it ain't free for calls to 3 or more participants).

Answer (score 2):

Skype is working on Group Video. Have a look at the [5.0 Beta](http://www.skype.com/intl/de/get-skype/on-your-computer/windows/beta/).

Source:
http://mashable.com/2010/05/05/skype-group-video-calling/

Answer (score 1):

Skype golden version 5.x is released, you can download from [skype official site](http://www.skype.com).

Answer (score 0):

Skype disables it for some odd reason.  Linux allows several skype instances.  I think you can open two skypes and call one-to-one with each skype instance.  However, I'm not sure if the webcam driver let's two applications read the camera at the same time.

Watch out for ooVoo!  Just a few hours after installing it, I had several viruses and had to reinstall Windows.  The exact same thing happened to about three other people that I know.